# how can I get an unchecked checkbox from a html form to php and give a value to it?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working in a blog and I'm trying to deal with the newsletter checkbox of the register form... when the user marks the checkbox I have no problem to get  'yes'  as result and I take that to the data base, but when the user leaves the checkbox unchecked I got an undefined index and just can't continue with the register, here's the code I have so far

the html form

```
<form method="POST" action="process-register.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="yes" />
</form>
```

the

```
//declared variable for the users input
$newsletter=$_POST['newsletter'];

//the condition for the checkbox
if(isset( $newsletter)){
$newsletter=="yes";
}else{
$newsletter=="no";
}

//then I insert the variable $newsletter through a prepared query...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use empty check.

```
if(!empty($_POST['newsletter'])){
}
```

Comment: I tried, but resulted the same                             if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])){
$newsletter=="si";
}else{
$newsletter=="no";
}

Comment: Also remove line: $newsletter=$_POST['newsletter'];

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` to see if the value was submitted at all instead.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things going on here. For one, you seem to be using `==` for assignment (in your condition for the checkbox), when you probably meant `=` instead. But the important bit is to define your variable with the "no" value as a default, then overwrite that with the posted value, if it's set.

Try

```
// set default value
$newsletter = "no";

// use posted variable if it's set
if (isset($_POST['newsletter'])) {
    $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];
}

// then insert the variable $newsletter through a prepared query...
```